# Show that for any function $f \in \mathcal L^{1}(\tau)$ the identity $\int_{\mathbb N} f(n) \tau(dn) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} f(n)$ holds.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Consider the measure space $(\mathbb N, \mathcal P(\mathbb N), \tau)$, where $\tau$ is the counting measure.

I've decided the system $\mathcal N_\tau$ of $\tau$-nullsets as the empty set.

I must show that for any function $f \in \mathcal L^{1}(\tau)$ the identity $$\int_{\mathbb N} f(n) \tau(dn) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} f(n)$$ holds, where the infinite sum converge absolutely.

> Here $\mathcal L^{1}(\tau)$ denote the set of Lebesgue integrable functions, such that both the positive and negative parts are integrable with value less than $\infty$.

I've tried using a main theorem of dominated convergence by Lebesgue but without luck.

Can someone help me out ?

Also if $f \in \mathcal L(\tau)$ then the limit $$\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$$ exist in $[-\infty, \infty]$, and we have $$ \int_{\mathbb N} f(n) \tau(dn) = \lim_{N \rightarrow \infty} \sum_{n=1}^N f(n)$$

> Here $\mathcal L(\tau)$ denote the set Lebesgue integrable functions, such that either the positive part or the negative part is integrable with value less than $\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Assume $f$ non-negative. Define the increasing sequence of simple functions $(g_i)$ by
$$g_i(n) =\begin{cases} f(n), & n\leq i\\ 0, & \text{else.}\end{cases}$$

Now what is $\int g_i(n) \tau(dn)$? Then use [monotone convergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem#Lebesgue.27s_monotone_convergence_theorem).

Also remember that a general $f$ can be represented by $f=f^+-f^-$ where $f^+$ is the positive part and $f^-$ is the negative part. Note $|f|=f^++f^-$.

Comment: I think that monotone convergence is easier than dominated convergence in this setting.

Comment: @PhoemueX yes, you are right!

Comment: Thanks, I will certainly try this out.

Comment: Is this correct ? $$\int f d \tau \le |\int f d \tau| \le \int |f| d \tau = \int f^+ + f^- d \tau = \int f^+ d \tau + \int f^- d \tau = \lim \int f^+ 1_{[1,n]} d \tau + \lim \int f^- 1_{[1,n]} d \tau = \lim \sum |f(n)| = \sum |f(n)|$$ ?